# UITableViewCell minimum height with automatically resizing cells

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uitableview

I am using automatically resizing *cells* in my project. I want to keep the *cells* at a minimum `height`, but I cannot set a minimum `height` *constraint* for my *cells* in my *Content View* (as it is greyed out in the **Add New Constraints** view:

[image]

Is there anyway to add minimum `height` *constraints* for my *cells*?

Comment: The content view size is supposed to depend on the table view behavior (style) and the actual content (subviews). The solution is simple: add a subview.

Comment: What @A-Live seems like the simplest solution.  You can add a hidden subview that's pinned to the top and bottom of your cell with a height constraint (width isn't relevant, but you'll need to specify it somehow to keep AutoLayout happy).

Comment: Thank you, this worked (although it isn't a very elegant solution...).

Answer (score 24):

When `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` is enabled the system calls `UITableViewCell`'s [systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:withHorizontalFittingPriority:verticalFittingPriority:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622623-systemlayoutsizefittingsize) method to calculate the cell height, so you can subclass `UITableViewCell` and override this method to force a minimum height for the cell, in this way

```
class MinHeightTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var minHeight: CGFloat?

    override func systemLayoutSizeFitting(_ targetSize: CGSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority horizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority, verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority) -> CGSize {
        let size = super.systemLayoutSizeFitting(targetSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority: horizontalFittingPriority, verticalFittingPriority: verticalFittingPriority)
        guard let minHeight = minHeight else { return size }
        return CGSize(width: size.width, height: max(size.height, minHeight))
    }
}
```

And then

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "minHeightCell", for: indexPath) as! MinHeightTableViewCell
    cell.minHeight = 62 // change with your desidered min height
    cell.textLabel?.text = "some text"
    return cell
}
```

Comment: This works well, but I'm curious: Where did you find out that systemLayoutSizeFitting gets called when UITableViewautomaticDimension is enabled? I can't find documentation on that anywhere.

Comment: `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` is called by system to get the size of the view based on its constraints. When `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` is enabled, table view uses auto layout to self sizing cells, and then it calls `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` on cell and that returns the size of the cell based on the layout constraints. I agree with you, this is not explicit.

Answer (score 10):

set a height constraint as `height >= 60.0` No need to do anything

Answer (score 6):

I added this constraint to my cell but in code (swift)

```
contentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
```

If your cell view needs more space:

```
contentView.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 80).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's code used in viewDidLoad. `cell` is the UITableViewCell. Notice the relatedBy parameter is >=.  44 is my minimum height...

```
[cell.contentView addConstraint: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: cell.contentView attribute: NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual toItem: nil attribute: NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier: 1 constant: 44]];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can makes your cells as dynamic height by returning the `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` in height calculation methods of tableview. But for this your cell design constraints should be like the below one

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

[image]

Note: Todo Title is the static height. And description will be dynamic height. So description does not own the height constrain. Important thing is you need set a number of lines as 0 for description label

Answer (score 2):

simple added height constraint with minimum height you want and then change it relation to "Greater then Equal to". look highlighted section of screen short.  [image]

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps, to set automatic dimension for cell with some minimum height.

- Assign and implement tableview dataSource and delegate
- Assign `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` to rowHeight & estimatedRowHeight
- Implement delegate/dataSource methods (i.e. `heightForRowAt` and return a value `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` to it)

-

**Objective C:**

```
// in ViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

  @property IBOutlet UITableView * table;

@end

// in ViewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.table.dataSource = self;
    self.table.delegate = self;

    self.table.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    self.table.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

**Swift:**

```
@IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Don't forget to set dataSource and delegate for table
    table.dataSource = self
    table.delegate = self

    // Set automatic dimensions for row height
    table.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    table.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}



// UITableViewAutomaticDimension calculates height of label contents/text
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

For label instance in UITableviewCell

- Set number of lines = 0 (& line break mode = truncate tail)
- Set all constraints (top, bottom, right left) with respect to its superview/ cell container.
- **Note: Set minimum height for label, if you want minimum vertical area covered by label, even if there is no data.**

[image]